# React-Native: Webview Javascript-Injection not working as expected

Tags: javascript, cookies, webview, react-native

**What I want to do:**
I make a fetch call, that gives me an API-token to login into a network. Now I want to inject a cookie (containing this api-token) into a Webview, so I should get logged in automatically.

**What I tried:**
I set up a Webview like so:

```
<WebView
        source={{uri:this.state.url}}
        onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this.url)}
        javaScriptEnabled = {true}
        injectedJavaScript={this.state.cookie}
      />
```

a little bit above I set cookie to:

```
cookie: 'document.cookie=\'apiToken=xxx; userId=1; expires=28799\'';
```

Also I loaded [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija) and injected the above line in Chrome and it works flawlessly..

I've read that the javascript gets injected after the view loaded, but this should still work, since I get redirected to 'domain/login', which should detect the cookie..

(I'm running react-native 0.29)
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code works just fine - my error was on a different end (I not knowingly changed this.url.. which called the wrong url)